# Обращение к таблицам google spreadsheet из редактора скриптов

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Делаю парсинг цен такой функцией:

```
function myFunction (pos, url) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();    
  var range = sheet.getRange(pos);               
  var cell = range.getCell(1,1);                 
 try {  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var textResp  = response.getContentText();      
  var start, end, value;                           
  start = textResp.indexOf('"price":"', end) + 9;
  end = textResp.indexOf('.00","list"', start);
  name = textResp.substring(start, end);
  cell.setValue(name);
  cell = cell.offset(0,1);
  start = textResp.indexOf('item_avb availability_', end) + 22;
  end = textResp.indexOf('"><link itemprop', start);
  value = textResp.substring(start, end);
  if (value == 'yes') cell.setValue('есть')
  else cell.setValue('на заказ')
  }
 catch (err) {
     cell.setValue('404!!!');
     }
 }
```

Обращение к листу `sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()`
А как обратится к листу документа не из которого зашел в редактор, а по имени? Листов в документе несколько и порой скрипт затирает мне не то что нужно...
И еще через `try catch` реализована обработка, если URL не доступен, но как -то корявенько выглядит. Может кто подскажет как поэстетичнее?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы выбрать лист по имени, нужно сначала взять указатель на таблицу ([getActiveSpreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivespreadsheet)), и затем использовать метод [getSheetByName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename). Пример:

```
var spr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = spr.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
```

Кстати, можно обращаться и к другим *таблицам*: см. [openById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid).

---

Вместо try... catch при использовании [UrlFetchApp.fetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl-params) лучше установить параметр `muteHttpExceptions: true`. Если запрос был неуспешным, выполнение скрипта продолжится, и код ответа (404, 500, 503, и т.п.) вернётся в объекте класса [HttpResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#methods). Пример:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
  // обработка данных 
}
else {
  Logger.log(response);   // неудача
  return; 
}
```